# Getting timestamps for each transcribed word through Google Cloud Speech API?

Tags: python, audio, google-cloud-platform, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I'm hoping to transcribe an audio file via the Google Cloud Speech API. This simple script takes a wav as input and transcribes it with pretty high accuracy.

```
import os
import sys
import speech_recognition as sr

with open("~/Documents/speech-to-text/speech2textgoogleapi.json") as f:
  GOOGLE_CLOUD_SPEECH_CREDENTIALS = f.read()
name = sys.argv[1] # wav file
r = sr.Recognizer()
all_text = []
with sr.AudioFile(name) as source:
  audio = r.record(source)
  # Transcribe audio file
  text = r.recognize_google_cloud(audio, credentials_json=GOOGLE_CLOUD_SPEECH_CREDENTIALS)
all_text.append(text)
with open("~/Documents/speech-to-text/transcript.txt", "w") as f:
  f.write(str(all_text))
```

How can I use the API to extract other meaningful information from the speech audio? Specifically, I'm looking to get a timestamp for each word, but other info (eg. pitch, amplitude, speaker recognition, etc.) would be extremely welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

There is actually an example on how to do this in the Speech API in

[Using Time offsets(TimeStamps)](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/async-time-offsets#speech-async-recognize-gcs-python):

> [Time offset (timestamp)](https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/basics#time-offsets) values can be included in the response text
>   for your recognize request. Time offset values show the beginning and
>   end of each spoken word that is recognized in the supplied audio. A
>   time offset value represents the amount of time that has elapsed from
>   the beginning of the audio, in increments of 100ms.
>
> Time offsets are especially useful for analyzing longer audio files,
>   where you may need to search for a particular word in the recognized
>   text and locate it (seek) in the original audio. Time offsets are
>   supported for all our recognition methods: recognize,
>   streamingrecognize, and longrunningrecognize. See below for an example
>   of longrunningrecognize.....

This is the code sample for Python:

```
def transcribe_gcs_with_word_time_offsets(gcs_uri):
    """Transcribe the given audio file asynchronously and output the word time
    offsets."""
    from google.cloud import speech
    from google.cloud.speech import enums
    from google.cloud.speech import types
    client = speech.SpeechClient()

    audio = types.RecognitionAudio(uri=gcs_uri)
    config = types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.FLAC,
        sample_rate_hertz=16000,
        language_code='en-US',
        enable_word_time_offsets=True)

    operation = client.long_running_recognize(config, audio)

    print('Waiting for operation to complete...')
    result = operation.result(timeout=90)

    for result in result.results:
        alternative = result.alternatives[0]
        print('Transcript: {}'.format(alternative.transcript))
        print('Confidence: {}'.format(alternative.confidence))

        for word_info in alternative.words:
            word = word_info.word
            start_time = word_info.start_time
            end_time = word_info.end_time
            print('Word: {}, start_time: {}, end_time: {}'.format(
                word,
                start_time.seconds + start_time.nanos * 1e-9,
                end_time.seconds + end_time.nanos * 1e-9))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Do you know if the results will be in temporal order? Is there a way to extract the times for when a speaker switches other than checking every word result?